# synchronized, когда изменяем, а volatile, когда читаем?

Tags: java

Изучаю multithreading. Прочитал и посмотрел какое-то количество материалов, в тоже время в голове каша и ответить, например, в каком случае надо применять synchronized, а в каком нет затрудняюсь.
Я правильно понял, что в общем случаем можно сказать, мол, если код в потоках может  одновременно читать из какой-то переменной, то ее необходимо пометить volatile, а если изменять какую-то переменную, то методы потока должны быть synchronized?
А если и читать и писать, то одновременное что ли?
Может быть есть возможность объяснить, словно шестилетнему ребенку?

Answer (score 3):

1. `synchronized` - означает, что к участку кода помеченному так может иметь доступ в один и тот же момент времени только один поток, таким образом обеспечивается атомарность изменений внутри блока `synchronized`
2. `volatile` - (применяется только по отношению к переменной) - означает, что переменная видима всем потокам и может ими изменяться - то есть обеспечивается только его видимость, но не атомарность.